# Using PHP - check if shopping cart is empty and, if so, display message

Tags: php

I'm new to php so I've struggled through each step of this assignment. I've hit a wall with this final step. I've built a simple shopping cart using only PHP (per the instructions). The index.php page contains all the items as well as a checkout button that redirects to the checkout.php page. If the user clicks this "checkout" button before items have been added to their cart, I need to display "Your cart is empty" message on the checkout page. I'm assuming I need to do the check on the checkout.php file. I've attempted it more than a dozen times without luck. Help is appreciated.

I'm including my attempted code on the checkout.php file

```
<?php

require_once('session_util.php'); 

if(isset($_SESSION[SHOPPING_CART]) && empty($_SESSION[SHOPPING_CART])) {
    echo 'Your shopping cart is empty.';
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Form 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <h2>Checkout</h2>
    <table id="cart">
        <?php
        // This is where session starts
        $itemArray = $_SESSION[SHOPPING_CART]->getItemArray();
        foreach ($itemArray as $item) {
            $name = $item->getName();
            $price = number_format($item->getPrice(), 2);

            echo "<tr>
                    <th>$name</th>
                    <th>$$price</th>
                  </tr>";
        }

        // you will get these from the shopping cart, not a specifc item
        $subTotal = number_format($_SESSION[SHOPPING_CART]->subTotal(), 2);
        $tax = number_format($_SESSION[SHOPPING_CART]->addTax(), 2);
        $total = number_format($_SESSION[SHOPPING_CART]->getTotal(), 2);

        // Display calculated subtotal, tax, and total.
        ?>
        <?php
        echo "
            <table id='total'>
            <tr><td>SubTotal &nbsp $$subTotal</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Tax &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp $$tax</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Total &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp $$total</tr></td>
            </table>
            ";
        ?>
    </table>
    <form id="keep_shopping" method="post" action="index.php">
        <input id="submit" type="submit" class="keep_shopping" name="keep_shopping" value="Keep Shopping">
    </form>
    <form id="empty_cart" method="post" action="clear_cart.php">
        <input id="submit" type="submit" class="empty_cart" name="empty_cart" value="Empty Cart">
    </form>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Edits and Infromation as asked in comment: 
`enter code here`session_start() is located in a separate file - session_util.php - and this file is required at the top of all other assignment files.
Also, when I do a var_dump on `$_SESSION[SHOPPING_CART]`; I get the following:

> object(ShoppingCart)#11 (1) { ["itemArray":"ShoppingCart":private]=>
>   array(0) { } }

Comment: add quotes. `$_SESSION["SHOPPING_CART"]`

Comment: Also please check you have writter session_start() before checking

Comment: $_SESSION[SHOPPING_CART] Please *print_r* this session. and then check how result are you getting and on basis of that please try to add a comment or please place that output over your question so we can help.

Comment: Thanks @YagnikDetroja  .. .I have the session_start() contained in the session_util.php file. This was a requirement in the assignment.  Everything is working perfectly except checking that items have been added to cart.  I'll do as you've requested now and post the response.

Comment: @YagnikDetroja.   The print_r  resulted in the following :                    
        ShoppingCart Object ( [itemArray:ShoppingCart:private] => Array ( ) )

Answer (score 0):

First of all there must be

`session_start()` on the php pages where you are accessing the session variables.

Then there is a syntax error, instead of

`$_SESSION[SHOPPING_CART]` it should be `$_SESSION["SHOPPING_CART"]` everywhere throughout the code.

Comment: At one point I also thought I needed the quotation marks. My professor confirmed that I don't and I've coded  $_SESSION[SHOPPING_CART] in this way in every file required for this assignment.  I honestly don't know why the quotes are not needed in this case as the book we sometimes reference during assignments does show quotation marks being used.  I do plan to get clarity on this when I submit the assignment.

Comment: Also... we have to add our session_start() to a session_util.php file and that file is required at the top of each file.

Comment: I guess the problem is the $_SESSION[SHOPPING_CART] contains an array, but that array is empty, that is why it is passing your check conditions because it is never empty, it contains a array which is empty. When you get `$itemArray` in your code, can you do a check at that point for checking if it is empty or not. May be checking if its length is equal to zero or not??